# GA4 cross domain measurement with client_id and session_id

Tags: google-analytics-4, gtag.js

According to https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10071811?hl=en#zippy=%2Cmanual-setup, I can use code similar to the following to set the client_id and session_id values for Google Analytics:

```
gtag('config','TAG_ID', {
  'client_id': getClientIdFromUrl(),
  'session_id': getSessionIdFromUrl()
});
```

However, what the page ***doesn't*** state is **when** I can call this.  Can I call this at *any* point, or does it need to be before any events have fired, etc.?

Comment: If you want to set the client_id and session_id values, it is best to call it as early as possible, preferably before any other events have fired. This is because the client_id and session_id values are used to uniquely identify a user's session, and if you set them after events have fired, it may not be possible to correctly associate those events with the correct user session.